Asyncio in corroutine RuntimeError: no running event loop in a discord bot code
This code belongs to a discord bot python script for calling of data for the stocks and all the libraries are up to date but the function called_once_a_day has an error which i can't seem to put my finger on.
Code for the function called_once_a_day:
@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def called_once_a_day():
URL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/^QMI"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
premarket = ""
try:
    current_price = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)"})[0].find_all("span")[0]
    change = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)"})[0].find_all("span")[1]
    premarket = "NASDAQ 100 Pre Market\t" + current_price.text + "\t" + change.text
except:
    premarket = "No data found"

for guild in bot.guilds:
    for channel in guild.channels:
        try:
            embed = get_news()
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
            await channel.send(premarket)
        except Exception:
            continue

Error in the program:
File "D:\Tradlytics\bot.py", line 173, in <module>
called_once_a_day.start()
File "C:\Users\kart1\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 398, in start
self._task = asyncio.create_task(self._loop(*args, **kwargs))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 381, in create_task
loop = events.get_running_loop()
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: no running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Loop._loop' was never awaited


remove the screenshots and provide code/error messages as text inside your question

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

@eshirvana thank you for the correction, made the changes and uploaded the code and error as text

@Friedrich thank you for the correction ,i've  uploaded the question and code in the right way now.
